# How to get data from a custom table into a block in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, block

I have followed the steps mentioned in the link below to create a custom module in magento 1.7.
http://www.webspeaks.in/2010/07/create-your-first-magento-module.html#comment-form

I did not create a web table, instead I have created 2 tables chefdetail and chefproduct, and have created the Block and phtml file for the same.

My Chefdetail block looks like:

```
class TruffleStreet_Web_Block_ChefDetail extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
public function _prepareLayout()
{
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

public function getChefDetail()
{
    if (!$this->hasData('chefdetail')) {
        $this->setData('chefdetail', Mage::registry('chefdetail'));
    }
    return $this->getData('chefdetail');

}
}
```

How do I modify it to load all the data from the chefdetail table in the database?  There is data in this table, but I am not able to access it.
My chefdetail.phtml file looks like:

```
$_chefblockData = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('web/chefdetail')->getChefDetail();
echo "Count Chef = " . count($_chefblockData) ;
```

Please advice how I can fix this issue?

Thanks,
Neet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this you will get all the customer details according to the email...

```
collection = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                  ->addFieldToFilter("email",$CustomerEmail);
```

You can change the email to customer Id also..

Comment: Hi,
I followed  your suggestion and it worked great. Thankyou so much.